# how to disable batch-saving pointclouds

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rgbd-slam, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Does anyone know how to disable batch-saving of point clouds? I found some relevant code on line 100 of node.cpp but don't really know what to do to disable it. I'm trying to slim down memory requirements so all I would require is the pose estimates.

Cheers,
Ken

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11703/how-to-disable-batch-saving-pointclouds/) by [KenHo](https://answers.ros.org/users/974/kenho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [new snapshot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam/evaluation) and set its parameter "store_pointcloud" and "use_glwidget" to false.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0